docker pr already using port when using docker compose on ubuntu 22
Weirdly enough everytime i mount something with docker compose, the container can't start because the port is use
when i look into it it's docker-pr usig the port

i know i need to kill the process then it work but look up process and killing it on every docker compose up is not normal
i shouldn't have to kill process when starting docker compose if no process on the linked port exist before up

Stopped containers still have any host ports allocated until you remove them with docker rm ... or docker compose down. To see all your containers, including stopped ones, use docker ps -a.

i had no containers at all, thoses ports are allocated when i docker compose up, it's like docker allocate the port of the container i want to start
